# split a row into multiple rows in sql server according to a specific column

Tags: sql-server

I have table a having fields id,val and identical table b having fields id,val.

when i am writing an inner join for different data in rows

> SELECT *  FROM a left join b on a.id = b.id   WHERE ( a.id != b.id or
>   a.val != b.val)

i am getting like below
[image]

i want to split this table row into two rows. Help me to write a query to split this data and getting an output table like below
[image]

Help!

Comment: `left join on a.id = b.id` wont return any (a.id <> b.id)

Answer (score 6):

You can generate the extra row(s) by doing an unpivot using a cross apply and the table value constructor.

```
select c.id,
       c.val
from dbo.a 
  inner join dbo.b
    on a.id = b.id
  cross apply (values(a.id, a.val),
                     (b.id, b.val)) as c(id, val)
where a.val <> b.val;
```

Comment: Comments [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57057/discussion-on-answer-by-mikael-eriksson-split-a-row-into-multiple-rows-in-sql-se) as requested.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your query uses `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id` you can change your WHERE clause to `WHERE (a.val != b.val)` because you wont receive any record where `a.id <> b.id`

That said, to divide the results you can use a UNION by selecting all records from table a, plus all records from table b that match your WHERE clause.

> ```
> create table a (id int, val varchar(10));
> create table b (id int, val varchar(10));
> insert into a values (1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc'),(4,'ddd');
> insert into b values (1,'ddd'),(5,'bbb'),(3,'xxx'),(7,'ddd');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM a left join b on a.id = b.id WHERE ( a.id != b.id or a.val != b.val)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | id | val
> -: | :-- | -: | :--
>  1 | aaa |  1 | ddd
>  3 | ccc |  3 | xxx
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.* FROM a left join b on a.id = b.id WHERE (a.val <> b.val)
> UNION
> SELECT b.* FROM a left join b on a.id = b.id WHERE (a.val <> b.val)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | :--
>  1 | aaa
>  1 | ddd
>  3 | ccc
>  3 | xxx
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=567c2d0889e5e55040870c6522a07089)*

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it Works for me

Comment: If it works pls accept this as an Ans