# "No column name was specified for column..." when aliasing results of CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I have this table:

[image]

from which I create this View:

[image]

This view's `CardId` allows me to `JOIN` against the `Card` table with so I can retrieve the `Count` from any `CardId`. Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        si.CardId SourceCardId,
        ti.CardId TargetCardId,
        (SELECT TOP 1 r.Name
        FROM dbo.Relationship r
        WHERE r.Id = rac.RelationshipId) [Name],
        Count(*) [Count]
    FROM dbo.Relationship_AcquiredCard rac
    JOIN dbo.AcquiredCard sac ON rac.SourceAcquiredCardId = sac.Id
    JOIN dbo.AcquiredCard tac ON rac.TargetAcquiredCardId = tac.Id
    JOIN dbo.CardInstance si ON sac.CardInstanceId = si.Id
    JOIN dbo.CardInstance ti ON tac.CardInstanceId = ti.Id
    GROUP BY si.CardId, ti.CardId, rac.RelationshipId
    -- you can probably ignore everything above
    ) X
CROSS APPLY
    (values (X.TargetCardId),
            (X.SourceCardId)
    ) whatdoesthisdo(CardId) --wut
```

What does `whatdoesthisdo` do? I got the `CROSS APPLY` from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/170904). If I try to alias in the usual way, I get this error:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be clear from the below

```
SELECT WhatDoesThisDo.CardId
FROM   (VALUES (1),
               (2) ) WhatDoesThisDo(CardId)
```

`WhatDoesThisDo` provides the table alias for the derived table defined by the `VALUES` clause. It then requires a comma delimited list of all column names (as there is no way of naming them inside the `VALUES` itself).

In this case it only returns one column so the complete column list is `(CardId)`

The relevant part of [the grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is

```
derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
```

though the optionality indicated by the square brackets above does not apply with table value constructors.